# select dot in scatter plot based on data id in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have initially ppopulated the scatter plot based on the data fetched from server in d3js. Now I intend to highlight the dots based on the data id.

Sample data set :

```
gdata = [{'pid': 161, 'cu': 4, 'ft': 2.8, 'car': 57.1},
        {'pid': 161, 'cu': 4, 'ft': 2.8, 'car': 57.1}
         ]

  func init() {
           // Some code 
         svg.selectAll(".dot")
            .data(gdata)
            .enter().append("svg:circle")
            .attr("class", "dot")
            .attr("r", 5.5)
            .attr("stroke", "")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.fats); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.carbs); })
            .style("fill", function(d) { 
                if (d.pid == $('#package_id').val()) {
                       return "red" ;
                }
                return "#1f77b4" ; /*(d.cuisine == 6 ? "#cfcfcf" : color(d.cuisine));*/ 
            });
       }
```

I am trying to create another function

```
//psuedocode
function highlight(subset) {
      subset =  {'pid': 161, 'cu': 4, 'ft': 2.8, 'car': 57.1} ;
      select that particular dot in scatter plot which represents that data point
      and style("fill", "red")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the highlighted dot is assumed to have been drawn already by `init()`, you don't need to do any data binding. Instead, you need to select the dots and adjust their fill based on their `d` and whether it appears in `subset`:

```
function highlight(subset) {
  svg.selectAll('.dot').style("fill", function(d) {
    var dIsInSubset = d.pid == subset.pid;
    return dIsInSubset ? 'red' : '#1f77b4'
  })
}
```

Comment: I actually came up with this solution : d3.select('body').selectAll('.dot').style("fill","#1f77b4")
               .data(gdata,function (d) {
                    return d.pid ==  $('#package_id').val() ;
               })
               .style("fill","red");
Which one do you suggest is more efficient ?

Comment: @Rahul I don't think the approach you propose is correct. It's inappropriate to rebind the data. First, it's inefficient, because d3 has to calculate the enter, exit and update selection. But more importantly, your use of the key function (second param of `data()`) is telling d3 that only the highlighted datum should remain, and everything else should be assigned to the `exit()` selection — even though you're not going to be calling `remove()` on them. I'm not sure, but there's a chance this has side effects like causing the datum to be disassociated from the non-highlighted elements.